# Does this paragraph make you want to keep reading?

Tags: fiction

> Can you remember the last toy you ever bought?
>
> We do.  Here at the St. Abattoir, London's largest toy store, your childhood is our business. We think of ourselves not as merely customer service representatives but as consumer psychologists—-predicting the next toy-*wunder*. If you’re in a “gift sized fix” and in need of the latest razzler dazzler—-you call us. We want you to buy. Preferably now, but if not now, there’s a wonderful savings plan we will tailor to your needs.  And we promise, that here at the St. Abattoir, during every phone call you’re guaranteed to hear:
>   “Hi there, my name is Charlie King. Thank you for calling, and how may I help you?”

Thank you for any feedback, I hope this adheres to the [community guidelines](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work). If not,  please let me know.

Comment: ...the toy store is named "abbatoir"? I don't think *anything* could induce me to purchase children's toys from F.A.O. Slaughterhouse. (Unless this is from a comedy-horror story.)

Comment: Thank you for your rather astute comment Lauren. It is a rather curious name isn't it? ;-)

Comment: If it's on purpose as a "Modest Proposal" kind of wink, it's perfect. :)

Comment: FYI, this is an older question. It's been bumped by the system because it's been retagged, as per [this](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/534/26).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two hooks here I find compelling:

- The first two lines give this great, "Why, of course we remember every toy you've ever played with, Sir" vibe - it's like a toy store crossed with Wodehouse's Jeeves. That's both unusual and kinda creepy. The concept of a huge organization cataloging everybody's childhood in minute detail is bizarre and fantastical, and has this great "formality/whimsey" tension I really like.
- The paragraph ends with a very odd boast - for some reason, it's important that all the receptionists introduce themselves as "Charles King." That's just weird, and obviously has a story behind it. My immediate thoughts are that this might be some kind of publicity thing, based on some kind of personality-based promotion - or, if this is in a science-fiction context, that there's some kind of cloning or personality duplication going on. All of these interest me.

So that's a great start :) But the middle hits what I'd consider a false note - the "consumer psychologists" lines. My instinct is that this mars the fantastical image I had from the first two lines - it seems to reduce a delightful impossibility to mere contemporary market research. The "gift size fix" and "razzler dazzler" phrases also don't fit with the proper, dignified facade I was imagining (perhaps entirely erroneously, of course).

I'd definitely read further, because this opening has at least the potential to lead to some things I'd consider a lot of fun. But the points I'd mentioned would have me worried I might be disappointed. At the very least, I'd read long enough to understand which of my interpretations are correct. I might read the whole thing even if they aren't, but I'd feel disappointed.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Standback. You definitely gave me some great twists in the story I can take. The contest didn't have a specific genre--free reign, really.It's the Sean O'Faolain Competition. The title is Thank You for Calling, How May I Help You? Charlie King is the main character, but your feedback has been substantial in this draft phase. The telesalesman who work at the St. Abbatoir do know quite a lot about toys.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the toy store would keep me reading for a bit longer.

I had trouble with the "ever" in the first line. The last toy I ever bought as a child, for myself? The last toy I ever bought as an adult, because I didn't know any children to buy toys for?

This line:  *If you’re in a “gift sized fix” and in need of the latest razzler dazzler—-you call us.*  seems unnecessary, and I agree with Standback that it doesn't quite fit the tone.

Comment: I agree about the oddness of "ever" in the first line. Either _Can you remember the last toy you ever bought?_ or _Can you remember the last toy you ever bought?_ would sound more natural to me.

Answer (score 1):

I like "We want you to buy. Preferably now, but if not now, there’s a wonderful savings plan we will tailor to your needs." It's perfect. You're honest, and willing to work with customers. I also agree with Standback about the oddness of the last line.